# SSH and TELNET at the same time with Socket

Tags: python, cisco

I try to make a script on Python capable to access on Cisco device via TELNET or SSH.

The code:

```
import socket
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from getpass import getpass

remote_host = raw_input("Enter IP Address: ")

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    if socket.connect_ex((remote_host, 23)) == 0:
       print 'Connection stablished via TELNET'
       device
       net_connect = ConnectHandler(**device)
       socket.close()
    elif socket.connect_ex((remote_host, 22)) == 0:
         print 'Connection stablished via SSH'
         device
         net_connect = ConnectHandler(**device)
         socket.close()
    else:
         print 'Unable to stablish the connection'
         socket.close()

username = raw_input("Enter Username: ")

device = {
    'device_type': 'cisco_ios',
    'ip': remote_host,
    'username': username,
    'password': getpass(),
}
```

What am I doing wrong? (I'm very newbie in Python, sorry for that).

Thanks a lot for your help and time.

Answer (score 1):

After review the code. Finally I could solve it!.

Let me share with you:

```
remote_host = raw_input("Enter IP Address: ")
device = {}

socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
if socket.connect_ex((remote_host, 23)) == 0:
    print 'Connection stablished via TELNET'
    device['device_type'] = 'cisco_ios_telnet'
    device['ip'] = remote_host
    device['username'] = raw_input("Enter Username: ")
    device['password'] = getpass()
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**device)
    socket.close()
elif socket.connect_ex((remote_host, 22)) == 0:
    print 'Connection stablished via SSH'
    device['device_type'] = 'cisco_ios_ssh'
    device['ip'] = remote_host
    device['username'] = raw_input("Enter Username: ")
    device['password'] = getpass()
    net_connect = ConnectHandler(**device)
    socket.close()
else:
    print 'Unable to connect'
    socket.close()
    net_connect.disconnect()
```